# Leading Zeros when using $ in dart

Tags: dart

```
int seconds = 8;
String s = 'Remaining time: $seconds s';
print(s);
```

Output:

> ```
> Remaining time 8 s
> ```

What is the best way to add a leading zero to get as output:

> ```
> Remaining time 08 s
> ```

Of course, if *seconds* is > 10, I don't want a leading zero.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.padLeft()` function on the string:

```
var seconds = 8;
print('${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'); //Print: 08
```